# How to use replace () to strip only non-accent characters

Tags: javascript

I need to remove only the special characters, no accent, etc.

Code:

```js
string = 'Matheus /()/-:< > Nascimento'.replace(?)

console.log(string) // Desired return value: Matheus Nascimento
```

Can someone help me how to do this?

Note: I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative character set to match anything but `\w\s` (permit only word characters and space characters);

```js
const string = 'Matheus /()/-:< > Nascimento'.replace(/[^\w\s]+/g, '');
console.log(string);
```

If you want to remove duplicated spaced too:

```js
const string = 'Matheus /()/-:< > Nascimento'
  .replace(/[^\w\s]+/g, '')
  .replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
console.log(string);
```

For the second code, just add whatever characters you want to permit to the character set:

```js
const string = 'ILUSÃO "CRACOLÂNDIA" - Alok, MC Hariel, MC Davi, MC Ryan SP, Salvador da Rima e Djay W (GR6 Explode)'
  .replace(/[^\w\sÃÂ,]+/g, '')
  .replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
console.log(string);
```

Comment: And if by chance the string is:

`` `string = 'ILLUSION" CRACOLÂNDIA "- Alok, MC Hariel, MC Davi, MC Ryan SP, Salvador da Rima and Djay W (GR6 Explode)' -` `

How do I remove only the characters? Because if I use your code, return it to me on the console:

`` `console.log (string) // return iluso cracolndia alok mc hariel mc davi mc ryan sp salvador da rima and djay w gr6 explode```

Comment: This is an English site. Please use English if you want others to understand you.

Comment: Thanks guys, I used your code and included a normalize () and it worked!

Comment: Just for reference, here's the code that preserves accented characters and removes non-letters: ```'ILUSÃO Matheus /()/-:< > Nascimento'.normalize('NFD').replace(/[^\w\s\u0300-\u036f]+/g, '');```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try:

```js
let test1 = 'Matheus /()/-:< > Nascimento';
let test2 = 'ILLUSION" CRACOLÂNDIA "- Alok, MC Hariel, MC Davi, MC Ryan SP, Salvador da Rima and Djay W (GR6 Explode)';
function replaco(string){
  return string.replace(/[^A-zÀ-ÿ ]+/g, '').replace(/\s{2,}/, ' ');
}
console.log(replaco(test1)); console.log(replaco(test2));
```